# What is the difference between "he is trustful", "he is trusting", "he is trusted", "he is trustworthy", "he is trusty", and "he is trustless"?

Tags: meaning

*Trustful* means “having or marked by a total belief in the reliability, truth, ability, or strength of someone.”

So, does *he is trustful* mean that he trusts other people or that he is an honest person whom everyone trusts?

Can anyone help me to distinguish among he is *trustful*, he is *trusting*, he is *trusted*,  he is *trustworthy*, he is *trusty*, and he is *trustless*?

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the point of the definition you quoted. In the definition, *someone* does not refer to the person who is *trustful*, but to another person in whose *reliability, truth, ability or strength* the trustful person has *a total belief*.

> He is trustful

He tends to trust people

> He is trusting

Means the same thing

> He is trusted

People trust him

> He is trustworthy

People should trust him

Answer (score 0):

English has a clear way to distinguish who is trusting whom.  A "truster" or "trustor" is the one doing the trusting, and "trustee" is the one trusted.  This is clear enough that the law has adopted those terms for setting up a trust, a legal entity set up by one person to allow his assets to be taken care of by another.

> The **trustor** creates the trust and names the **trustee**.

English also has clear ways to describe which direction the trust flows:  to -- "trusted," "trustworthy"; from -- "trusting":

> I am a **trusting** person:  my friends are all **trusted**, as I consider
>   them all **trustworthy**.

Considering how important it is to know who is doing the trusting, it's interesting to note that three words are ambiguous:

- #### "trustful"

  **trusted**: From Sir Philip Sidney's [translation of
  Psalm 7:1](https://archive.org/stream/psalmsofsirphili00unse/psalmsofsirphili00unse_djvu.txt):

  > O Lord, my God, thou art my **trustfull** stay;

  or in the words of the King James Version, "O Lord my God, in thee do
  I put my trust."

  **trusting**: From Alfred Lord Tennyson's [*in memoriam*](http://archive.org/stream/inmemoriambyalfr00tennuoft/inmemoriambyalfr00tennuoft_djvu.txt), describing his
  his friend Arthur Henry Hallam:

  > And manhood fused with female grace
  >  In such a sort, the child
  >   would twine 
  >  A **trustful** hand, unask'd, in thine,
- #### "Trustless"

  (not to be) **trusted**:  From [*Last Days*](https://books.google.com/books?id=RTtVAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=irving%20last%20days%20trustless&source=bl&ots=FvNCyKV0Ef&sig=yISX0cP7svaQ6bbbuMeovpn6KM4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAWoVChMIwqzU-eaJxwIVR3o-Ch3OWA-Z#v=onepage&q=irving%20last%20days%20trustless&f=false) of Edward Irving, founder of the Apostolic Catholic Church, originator
  the of idea of the rapture, and professional scold, citing evidence
  of the breakdown of society:

  > Is not every **trustless** servant evidence of the same?

  (not) **trusting**:  From a despairing verse of 19th century poet Eliza
  Cook's "[Lines Written at Midnight](https://books.google.com/books?id=QasVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=eliza%20cook%20lines&source=bl&ots=n2Jthrmznd&sig=oi9fj-Bve4QvPOmMRZbL5yyPVZI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBmoVChMIj7GO_-uJxwIVgzc-Ch13QgJV#v=onepage&q&f=false), in the anticipation of a dreaded
  bereavement":

  > Though young in years, I've learnt to look
  >   With **trustless** eye on all and each;
  >   And shudder that I find so oft,
  >   The coldest heart with gentlest speech
- #### "Trusty"

  **trusting**: From the *OED* entry:

  > "1908 Times 28 July 4/1 A very intimate and **trusty** friendship sprang
  >   up between them."

  **trusted**:  From John Chambers' [*Divine Worship in England in the Thirteenth and Fourteenth Centuries*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4rFLAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq=%22chambers%22%20divine%20worship%20%22trusty%20person%22&source=bl&ots=wansMO7mCk&sig=epTNsbfEMF6gFDdM5QjKXNLrBr0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIicH5sPKJxwIVg3c-Ch2YugLA#v=onepage&q=%22chambers%22%20divine%20worship%20%22trusty%20person%22&f=false), describing how the flour
  for the sacramental host should be treated:

  > When wanted it should be carried to the mill by a **trusty**
  >   person,and then separately ground in a hand or other mill....

Thank you, *OED*, for definitions, quote, and pointers to sources.